# Unable to upload file (using Roxy Fileman) on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, upload, roxy-fileman

[Roxy Fileman](http://www.roxyfileman.com/) is a file manager that I'm using with TinyMCE4 to upload files.

I can't upload files on IE. Works great on Firefox and Chrome but I need to make it work on IE as well..

I keep getting this error:
"Could not find a part of the path C:UsersSarahDocumentsPicture.png".

I don't even understand why the path doesn't have "/"!

I tried to contact the developer but he never replied.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated...I've been trying to fix this for days now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up to find a solution!

For those who might have problems uploading files using IE, meaning that these error messages are showing up everytime:
- "Could not fine part of the path ''"
OR
- "Access to the path '' is denied."

Check your IE settings:
The IE security setting 'Include local directory path when uploading files to a server' should be DISABLED.

After setting that option, everything should work just fine!